# How to Pause SpriteKit scene upon press of Siri Button on the Siri Remote for AppleTV tvOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, tvos, apple-tv

There seems to be a bug with AppleTV. I have a SpriteKit scene with an SKNode 'worldNode' that contains all game nodes (and actions). I am able to detect when the Menu button is pressed on the Siri Remote and so in the SKScene I call

```
worldNode.paused = true
```

This pauses everything under worldNode as expected, including actions.
Now, to detect when the Siri Button is pressed my understanding is that `applicationWillResignActive` gets triggered in AppDelegate. So inside `applicationWillResignActive` I post a notification with

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ApplicationWillResignActive", object: nil)
```

The notification is received by my SKScene with the received notification's respective selector triggering `worldNode.paused = true`
However, this does NOT pause everything under worldNode like it does when called normally from within the scene! I find some actions nested under worldNode are still running!

Is there a work around? Is this a bug?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299905/spritekit-how-to-correctly-pause-and-resume-app

Answer (score 1):

In your scene when the Menu Button is pressed call:

```
self.scene!.view!.paused = true
```

and use:

```
self.scene!.view!.paused = false
```

to resume.