# call function in Appdelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have this function in gamescene.swift:

```
func pauseGame() {

    scene!.view!.paused = true
    println("pause")
    updateScoreTimer.invalidate()

}
```

Now I want to call it from the AppDelegate.swift but I don't know what to insert into "<#GameScene#>"

`GameScene.pauseGame(<#GameScene#>)`

Comment: What is the parameter for?

Comment: That's the thing: I need to insert a parameter but the function has no. And when I delete the parameter there is an error: "missing argument for parameter #1 in call"

Comment: You're trying to call an instance method but you're prefixing the call with the class name (like you're calling a class method). You need an instance of `GameScene` to call your `pauseGame` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your AppDelegate.swift instantiates the scene, you would call the method on the scene instance from app delegate. However I don't see why you would want to pause the game from appDelegate. Are you wanting to call this when the app launches?

Comment: I want to call this function when the app will enter the background or it will resign active.

Comment: I thought that might be what you want. But doesn't leaving the scene pause when you put the app in the background anyway?

Comment: This might solve part of your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014012/sprite-kit-the-right-way-to-multitask

Comment: So maybe what you want to do is hold on to an instance of your scene in appDelegate, and then in applicationWillResignActive call your method on the instance of the scene.