# iOS 7.1 Sprite Kit AVAudioSession Crash when enter background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit, ios7.1

So 2 weeks ago I submitted a sprite kit app to the app store and it all was fine. I was having problems before i submitted the app where it would crash because of AvAudioSession, however i was able to fix that problem through this [Sprite Kit & playing sound leads to app termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976813/sprite-kit-playing-sound-leads-to-app-termination). This basically sets AVAudioSession to inactive when going into background and then active again when coming into foreground. I recently update my phone it iOS 7.1 and this fix doesn't seem to work in the new 7.1 and my app is again crashing whenever it enters the background. I have taken all the audio out of my app and it seems to work fine so it is the same problem as i had before just now the solution doesn't work!I really need to fix this problem as i have an update ready to submit..
Cheers Sam

Comment: Any help from Apple Dev Forums?

Comment: Do you use runAction ^completion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did it!

I just paused the SKView in`- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` and included the AVAudioSession set to inactive.

AppDelegate.h

```
   #import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
```

AppDelegate.m

```
 - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
      {
// prevent audio crash
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];

SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
view.paused = YES;
 }


  - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
   {

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
}


  - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
   {
SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
view.paused = NO;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

adding to @ObjectivesCsam answer:

when rootViewControllers view is not SKView u can use

```
- (SKView *)getGameView {
    NSArray *viewControllers = self.window.rootViewController.childViewControllers;
    for (UIViewController *vc in viewControllers) {
        if ([vc.view isKindOfClass:[SKView class]]) {
            SKView *view = (SKView *)vc.view;
            return view;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```