# Not getting file URL from bundle

Tags: swift3, ios11

I am loading PDF file in PDFView but unable to get PDF File URL from Bundle.

**Please check below code :**

```
let pdfView = PDFView(frame: self.view.bounds)
let myFileName = "sample"
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: myFileName, withExtension: "pdf") else {
         return
}
pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)

self.view.addSubview(pdfView)
```

Every time I am getting `nil` in `url`.

**Edit :**

Here is my Project Window:

[image]

Am I making any silly mistake ?

Please guide me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your project window?  I'd like to see if/how you are including your `sample.pdf` into your application bundle.

Comment: I have added my Project Window please check my updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got problem not sure it's in Latest XCode but in XCode 9.5(Beta) while you adding any external file in your project and select bundle target still its not adding into bundle.

**Solution :**

You need to click on file which you want to add into your target bundle and check manually from property window.

**Please check below screen shot from more detail:**

While adding file into project I have checked it but still its not adding in selected target.

[image]

Now what I need only check related target and its working as expected.

[image]

Not sure its a bug or new update in Latest XCode.

But my problem is solved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not making a silly mistake.

I believe you simply need to add your `pdf` file as a resource to be copied.

Go into your Project's Build Phases and click on "Copy Bundle Resources" and then add "sample.pdf" to the list of files being copied, like this:

[image: Add File to list of files to be copied]

And then make sure it appears in that list, like this:

[image: Sample.pdf appears here]

Comment: Thanks @Michael I have solved my problem but with different approach and yes your solution also works well to solve my problem.

Comment: Right.  Adding the pdf file as a "target member" is essentially doing the same thing as what I did up above.